# Cocoapod OpenSSL installation issue

Tags: ios, openssl, cocoapods

I am trying to install OpenSSL Cocoapod into my iOS project.

Here is the code in my Podfile:

```
platform :ios, '10.3'

target 'MyApp' do

  use_frameworks!

  pod 'OpenSSL', '~> 1.0'

end
```

When I run "pod install" in the terminal I am getting this error and the installation stops.

```
[!] /bin/bash -c 
set -e
VERSION="1.0.2j"
SDKVERSION=`xcrun --sdk iphoneos --show-sdk-version 2> /dev/null`
MIN_SDK_VERSION_FLAG="-miphoneos-version-min=7.0"

BASEPATH="${PWD}"
CURRENTPATH="/tmp/openssl"
ARCHS="i386 x86_64 armv7 armv7s arm64"
DEVELOPER=`xcode-select -print-path`

mkdir -p "${CURRENTPATH}"
mkdir -p "${CURRENTPATH}/bin"

cp "file.tgz" "${CURRENTPATH}/file.tgz"
cd "${CURRENTPATH}"
tar -xzf file.tgz
cd "openssl-${VERSION}"

for ARCH in ${ARCHS}
do
  CONFIGURE_FOR="iphoneos-cross"

  if [ "${ARCH}" == "i386" ] || [ "${ARCH}" == "x86_64" ] ;
  then
    PLATFORM="iPhoneSimulator"
    if [ "${ARCH}" == "x86_64" ] ;
    then
      CONFIGURE_FOR="darwin64-x86_64-cc"
    fi
  else
    sed -ie "s!static volatile sig_atomic_t intr_signal;!staticvolatile intr_signal;!" "crypto/ui/ui_openssl.c"
    PLATFORM="iPhoneOS"
  fi

  export CROSS_TOP="${DEVELOPER}/Platforms/${PLATFORM}.platform/Developer"
  export CROSS_SDK="${PLATFORM}${SDKVERSION}.sdk"

  echo "Building openssl-${VERSION} for ${PLATFORM} ${SDKVERSION} ${ARCH}"
  echo "Please stand by..."

  export CC="${DEVELOPER}/usr/bin/gcc -arch ${ARCH} ${MIN_SDK_VERSION_FLAG}"
  mkdir -p "${CURRENTPATH}/bin/${PLATFORM}${SDKVERSION}-${ARCH}.sdk"
  LOG="${CURRENTPATH}/bin/${PLATFORM}${SDKVERSION}-${ARCH}.sdk/build-openssl-${VERSION}.log"

  LIPO_LIBSSL="${LIPO_LIBSSL} ${CURRENTPATH}/bin/${PLATFORM}${SDKVERSION}-${ARCH}.sdk/lib/libssl.a"
  LIPO_LIBCRYPTO="${LIPO_LIBCRYPTO} ${CURRENTPATH}/bin/${PLATFORM}${SDKVERSION}-${ARCH}.sdk/lib/libcrypto.a"

  ./Configure ${CONFIGURE_FOR} --openssldir="${CURRENTPATH}/bin/${PLATFORM}${SDKVERSION}-${ARCH}.sdk" > "${LOG}" 2>&1
  sed -ie "s!^CFLAG=!CFLAG=-isysroot ${CROSS_TOP}/SDKs/${CROSS_SDK} !" "Makefile"

  make >> "${LOG}" 2>&1
  make all install_sw >> "${LOG}" 2>&1
  make clean >> "${LOG}" 2>&1
done 


echo "Build library..."
rm -rf "${BASEPATH}/lib/"
mkdir -p "${BASEPATH}/lib/"
lipo -create ${LIPO_LIBSSL}    -output "${BASEPATH}/lib/libssl.a"
lipo -create ${LIPO_LIBCRYPTO} -output "${BASEPATH}/lib/libcrypto.a"

echo "Copying headers..."
rm -rf "${BASEPATH}/opensslIncludes/"
mkdir -p "${BASEPATH}/opensslIncludes/"
cp -RL "${CURRENTPATH}/openssl-${VERSION}/include/openssl" 
"${BASEPATH}/opensslIncludes/"

cd "${BASEPATH}"
echo "Building done."

echo "Cleaning up..."
rm -rf "${CURRENTPATH}"
echo "Done."
```

I found [this](https://github.com/FredericJacobs/OpenSSL-Pod/issues/32) thread on github. According to the thread there should be either /tmp/openssl folder or Xcode has a different name. There is no /tmp/openssl folder and Xcode is named Xcode only. I couldn't find any other link which resolves this issue.

Please help me with this installation.

Answer (score 4):

Probably, there is a misconfiguration in your Xcode... try this:

> preferences -> Locations -> Set The command line tools.

Sometimes when you update xcode this option auto deselects itself...

Comment: I've been debugging the original issue for hours, and have not seen a single suggestion to check "Command Line Tools" in Xcode's preferences. Sure enough this was exactly my issue. Thank you!